# NSIS custom page input from command line

Tags: arguments, installation, nsis, silent

I wrote an installation to my program using nsis.
It should be installed on multiple machines, so I'm trying to execute it from the command line but I have a custom page that includes a text box.

The page has only one textbox:

> Num of services to install

I'm trying to execute it like:

```
C:\install.exe /S 8 C:\MyDir\   (Second paramter is the INSDIR for the next page)
```

but it isn't working.

Any idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `/S` parameter is reserved for silent installs (not sure if it can be overridden). To provide `$INSTDIR` as parameter, you can use the reserved parameter `/D` (see the [examples](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter3.html#installerusageexamples)).

Since you haven't provided the code you're currently using, here's a generic example of how to parse command-line parameters:

```
!include "FileFunc.nsh"

Var NumServices

Function .onInit
    ${GetParameters} $0
    ${GetOptions} $0 "/services=" $NumServices
Function
```

The number of services is stored in the global variable `$NumServices` and you can use it on your nsDialogs (or InstallOptions) page.

Comment: Can't I inject value without changing my nsis code?

Comment: /S and /D are parsed before .onInit, you cannot override them.

Comment: Okay, i used GetParmeters. Thanks